# Increase variable if an action has happened

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

I am currently working on a website, on this website I have a Facebook share button and a Twitter tweet button. Then I have a javascript variable set to 0, now the problem I am having is that I would like to check if a person has shared on Facebook and made a tweet on Twitter by increasing the variable by 1 for when sharing on Facebook and increasing by 1 when tweeting and then if the variable is 2 then I would like to create a pop up.

I have gotten this which is the Facebook button

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/da_EN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then I have the tweet button

```
<div id="twitbut">
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://weiskleint.com/" data-text="Sign up for this awesome brand launching soon!" data-via="Weiskleint" data-hashtags="weiskleint">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
</div>
```

And lastly the Javascript variable which I have in the same html script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var shares=0;

            if (shares == 2)

        </script>
```

My issue is that I am not really sure how to check if a person has shared on Facebook or Twitter, but I would think I have to get the variable in the button codes and then when a person clicks that button it would increase the variable. But then if I were to do it like this, wouldn't you just have to click the button and then the person doesn't have to share the actual post? which is kind of the goal.

I am sorry if it is a bit cluttered, but in simple what I want to do is ask the user to share on both Facebook and Twitter and if the person does this they are rewarded with a coupon code. This code would then be in a pop up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if (shares = 2)` ==> `if (shares == 2)`

Comment: You might just want two variables `sharedFacebook` and `sharedTwitter` to avoid any problems with sharing on one site twice and having shares equal 2.

Comment: @IrkenInvader so instead of having it as numbers I would just have two boolean variables. One saying false and true to sharedFacebook and one saying false and true for sharedTwitter am I right? Then I would just have the Facebook share and Twitter tweet buttons change those variables to true? Then the only issue is how I get the buttons to do so.

Comment: Yep, just start with them both false and turn them on after sharing.  Have `if(sharedFacebook && sharedTwitter) showCouponPopup()` after hitting either share button.  Not sure about ensuring they actually share instead of just hitting the buttons though.

Comment: _“and then the person doesn't have to share the actual post? which is kind of the goal.”_ – You should stop right there – what you are trying to do is not allowed by Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5 // And Like-Gating is also not allowed any more.

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate the information, I wasn't aware of those rules as I had seen someone else do it.

Answer (score 2):

The method based on subscribing to the click event on the buttons is not reliable. You absolutely do not know if the user did or didn't like your page.

If you do it for business purpose, please stop!

The only safe way to know if the user did like your page is by having him authenticate via facebook/twitter, then ask their apis.

I think you should take a look to :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

Comment: The information is really appreciated as I am going to use it for a business and it is just for an email signup campaign which will run for a week so really it isn't as necessary. But you say if the user likes the page, is it also like this for shares? I just want to know if the user has shared the link to make a bouncing effect.

Comment: _“The only safe way to know if the user did like your page is by having him authenticate via facebook/twitter, then ask their apis”_ – but Facebook will not approve your app to request the necessary permission from the user, for the purpose of finding out whether they like a specific page. Like-Gating in any way, shape or form is not allowed any more.

Comment: CBroe Well, the link to fb doc above informe us about an API for getting the pages liked for a user. There should be a way check if our page is present in the returned JSON.

DevLiv : but CBroe is right, this practice is not encouraged anymore.

Comment: @dvxam: I did not say that the API does not provide it; but that Facebook will not approve the use of the necessary permission [in review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review), if your app tries to use it for the single purpose of checking if the user likes a single specific page. That is clearly stated here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_likes